# Box2d fixture definition parameters

Tags: android, box2d, andengine, game-physics

I'm develepoing a game via Andengine for Android. In my game, there a player and a moving box. This box moving in loop from (0,0) to (200,0) points.The problem is: when this box is changing its moving side, the player, which is on this box at the moment, is sliding. I don't want sliding!  Here is the codes:

Player:

```
final FixtureDef fixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0, 0, 0.1f);
this.body = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, this, BodyType.DynamicBody, fixtureDef);
```

Box:

```
final FixtureDef fixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(1, 0.1f, 0.5f);
this.body = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, this, BodyType.KinematicBody, fixtureDef);
```

Comment: Try making the friction values higher.

Comment: when I increase friction, the player can't move on it

Comment: So... it solves your problem then, right? :) Maybe you could add some more explanation about what you need. In any case, the player will move if the sideways force is high enough.

Comment: I want: player can move on box fluently when I press move button(let's say walk button). But when the player standing on box, and when box is moving and turning back, the player must be the same point on box(because I'm not press walk button at the moment).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that only changing fixture definition help with this problem.

You can use prismatic joint and join box and player while player standing on box. When player want move just destroy joint, and again create join when player stop moving on box.